# Slow performance reading (and writing) to a simple table

Tags: sql-server, performance

For some part of my application I need a "calculated object" where the heavy lifting of all calculations, grouping and other useful stuff is done overnight (batched process). Therefor I created a very simple table holding a UserIdentifier (ID) and a serialized JSON object (since my front end does all the displaying - I have no need to transform the object to anything else), so my table creation looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalculatedModel](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CalculatedModel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) 
) 
GO
```

Where I can I do cache the results in a distributed memorycache, but for some operations I just need all results, hence a:

```
SELECT * FROM CalculatedModel
```

On the staging server (which is a mirror of production) with the `select *` I get the whopping response time of 9 seconds read for ~85 records whereas production is a multitude of this number of records. Furthermore - writing to this table (in the midnight batch) after truncating the table results in (almost every night) a timeout on the insert of one the calculated models.

Using the execution plan and everything there is not a lot going on - almost no I/O operations, a clustered index scan of nothing, an average of 4015B row size (which can grow) - how to speed this up?

I've already changed from nvarchar to varchar since it's just plain ASCII - but that didn't help much - there is already an index on ID (but that isn't used for the "get all" method) - I have no idea why it's this slow and how to go on from this point.

As per question : this is the execution plan XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.539" Build="15.0.2101.7" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="8" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="150" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0032908" StatementText="SELECT *&#xD;&#xA;  FROM redacted.[dbo].[CalculatedModel]" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x3E4C27C2654A6D8E" QueryPlanHash="0x41958009A2AFC17B" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="88">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" GrantedMemory="0" MaxUsedMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="417267" EstimatedPagesCached="208633" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="4" MaxCompileMemory="14876512" />
            <TraceFlags IsCompileTime="true">
              <TraceFlag Value="8017" Scope="Global" />
            </TraceFlags>
            <TraceFlags IsCompileTime="false">
              <TraceFlag Value="8017" Scope="Global" />
            </TraceFlags>
            <WaitStats>
              <Wait WaitType="ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" WaitTimeMs="303" WaitCount="10541" />
            </WaitStats>
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="92" ElapsedTime="386" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4051" EstimateCPU="0.0001658" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="8" EstimatedRowsRead="8" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032908" TableCardinality="8">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[redacted]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CalculatedModel]" Column="ID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[redacted]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CalculatedModel]" Column="Model" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="8" ActualRowsRead="8" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="3" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[redacted]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CalculatedModel]" Column="ID" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[redacted]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CalculatedModel]" Column="Model" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[redacted]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[CalculatedModel]" Index="[PK_CalculatedModel]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Statistics returned this:

```
Table 'CalculatedModel'. 
Scan count 1, 
logical reads 3, 
physical reads 0, 
page server reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 0, 
page server read-ahead reads 0, 
lob logical reads 331062, 
lob physical reads 0, 
lob page server reads 0, 
lob read-ahead reads 468754, 
lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

As requested: one execution:

Actual Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJDsC_El2

Statistics IO

```
Table 'CalculatedModel'. 
Scan count 1, 
logical reads 3, 
physical reads 1, 
page server reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 0, 
page server read-ahead reads 0, 
lob logical reads 331062, 
lob physical reads 1561, 
lob page server reads 0, 
lob read-ahead reads 468754, 
lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

Client Statistics:

```
Client Execution Time   16:25:34        
Query Profile Statistics                            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    0       
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       
  Number of SELECT statements       1       
  Rows returned by SELECT statements        82      
  Number of transactions        0       
Network Statistics                          
  Number of server roundtrips           1       
  TDS packets sent from client      1       
  TDS packets received from server      109763      
  Bytes sent from client            112     
  Bytes received from server        4.495862E+08        
Time Statistics                         
  Client processing time            3319        
  Total execution time          3331        
  Wait time on server replies           12
```

Client side code (Service layer)

```
private string ListAllCalculatedUserModelsCacheKey => $"{_configuration.ClientID}-Service.ListAllCalculatedUserModels";

        public List<ServiceModels.CalculatedUserModel> ListAllCalculatedUserModels()
        {
            if (_memoryCache != null)
            {
                if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(ListAllCalculatedUserModelsCacheKey, out var _cache)) return (List<ServiceModels.CalculatedUserModel>)_cache;
            }

            var value = new Data.CalculatedModel(_configuration.ConnectionString).List();
            if (_memoryCache != null)
            {
                _memoryCache.Set(ListAllCalculatedUserModelsCacheKey, value, new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0));
            }
            return value;
        }
```

Actual data-layer:

```
  internal List<ServiceModels.CalculatedUserModel> List()
        {
            var value = new List<ServiceModels.CalculatedUserModel>();
            using (var sql = new SqlServer(_connectionstring))
            {
                sql.NewCommand("CalculatedModel_List");
                -- LINE BELOW = ~ 9 seconds
                var table = sql.Select().Tables[0];
                -- AFTER THIS = 1 second or less
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    value.Add(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceModels.CalculatedUserModel>(Conversion.ToString(row["Model"])));
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

Where stored procedure CalculatedModel_List is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculatedModel_List]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM CalculatedModel
END
GO
```

SqlServer is a simple helper class - nothing fancy. Just execute Stored Procedure, get a DataAdapter and return a DataSet. Reading one comment below: "don't blame the slow query" is not the case here: the `SELECT *` itself is the 9 seconds wait, handling afterwards is a fraction of the time.
Even when the query is executed on the same server with SSMS (first time) the query takes ~ 9 seconds for returning results in SSMS.

Comment: Can you paste the "actual execution plan" XML for one of the slow runs? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ You've concluded there is "not a lot going on" but likely you've missed something. w.r.t. wait stats or number of reads for example.

Comment: @MartinSmith see edit or https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rksmnM0J2

Comment: So that took 386 ms to return 8 rows - but its saying that 303 ms was spent waiting on the results to be sent to the client and the client to consume them (ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits) - the `ActualElapsedms` on the scan itself is showing up as 0 ms

Comment: What happens if you _don't_ render the results in SSMS (e.g. check `Query > Query Options > Results > Discard results after execution` first)? Or better yet, try from a copy of SSMS that is a lot closer to the data? How long it takes to get the data over the network to your client and then for your client to consume and render it in some grid should not be considered part of the query's performance unless that's how the query will always be consumed.

Comment: One thing which does seem weird is the sheer number of ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits though. The scan only does 3 logical reads - so max 24KB (unless you are using compression) - so this should be about 4 packets at default size  - so unclear how it accumulated 10,541 distinct waits on that type. What application are you running this in? And is it over some dodgy network?

Comment: @MartinSmith this execution plan is from the local machine, on staging we have SSMS installed for just these things. This wait time is in SSMS and from the application both - both have very very long wait times for the data to be returned. The application is NOT on the same server though - UI and data have separate servers.

Comment: If you add: set statistics io on; set statistics time on; before running the query, what does it say

Comment: do you have some weird filegroups?

Comment: 1 primary filegroup - @siggemannen you mean client statistics right?

Comment: No, set statistics is a sql server command to return some more info. it shows compilation time among others. But client statistics is good too, maybe there's something interesting there

Comment: Added statistics to the question

Comment: The execution plan XML in the question has `ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0"` so there is an inconsistency there

Comment: Can you paste Actual execution plan XML,`STATISTICS IO` results and client statistics results all belonging to the same execution? Does look like probably the data is bigger than the 4015B row size stated causing high lob reads, large number of bytes returned to the client and large ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits though

Comment: @MartinSmith added info to the question - although selection now took roughly 4 seconds (which is still long), but I did the SELECT * a couple of times to get all the analytics - and it's Sunday, so "slow day"

Comment: So 82 rows and 449586200 bytes means each row is 5.48 million bytes and it is the client application that is taking the time to process this amount of data not the server. The index scan to get this data only took 0.001s. It was primarily waiting on the client to consume and process the data (high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits and high Client processing time) - so the thing you need to be optimising is the client code that does this select and processing of results, and you haven't shown us that

Comment: As the issue is client side not the server there is no point running it in SSMS to reproduce BTW as the performance characteristics of how SSMS deals with that amount of data are not relevant to how your own code will

Comment: @MartinSmith added code that handles the data

Comment: @riffnl read [newtonsofr docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm), it specifically says, *"Allocating too many objects or allocating very large objects can slow down or even halt an application while garbage collection is in progress."* i have no clue why did you dump json into a single column, but you should fetch all rows before trying to deserialize them. it will still be slow though - at least the query finished earlier without hold ups.

Comment: it would be nice if you could narrow down the problem bit-by-bit before blaming slow query.

Comment: @BagusTesa The select is 9 seconds. The conversion a mere fraction of that. Depending on load ~1 second or less. All data is loaded into a single datatable. The select itself (the running of the stored procedure) is the 9 seconds, not the handling. That's also why I tried running it in SSMS (same result) approx 9 seconds even when SSMS is on the same machine.

Comment: Please show the create statements for all indexes

Comment: @Bohemian see create table (first code) in question